# hide a form on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I have listed the Marionette application below and the HTML follows.  I would like to make it so that the form would disappear from the page when the "process" button is pressed.  In the hideForm method I have a few things I have tried to hide the form on the click event.  Out of those attempts only this command "$('.form').hide()" works.  The problem is it only partially works in that once the button is clicked the form disappears but then immediately reappears.  Ultimately I would like to know what I am doing wrong but if anyone can tell me why the other methods I have in the hideform method do nothing at all I would love an explanation.

```
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
formBox : '#formBox',
listBox : '#listBox'
});

Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    entry : 'Blank'
},
});

EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Entry
});

FormView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
tagName: 'form',
template: '#form-template',
className: 'form',

events:{
    'click #processInput' : 'hideForm'
},

hideForm : function(){
    //$('.form').css('display','none')
    //document.getElementById("form").style.display="none";
    $('.form').hide();
}

});

EntryView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
tagName: 'tr',
template: '#entry-template',
className: 'entry',

events: {
    'click .delete' : 'destroy'
},

destroy : function()
{
    this.model.destroy();
}
});

EntriesView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
tagName: 'table',
template: '#entries-template',
itemView: EntryView,

appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
    collectionView.$('tbody').append(itemView.el);      
}
});

MyApp.addInitializer(function(test){
    var entriesView = new EntriesView({
    collection: test.entry
    });

    var formView = new FormView();
    MyApp.formBox.show(formView); 
    MyApp.listBox.show(entriesView);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var ents = new EntryList([
    new Entry({ entry: 'test a' }),
    new Entry({ entry: 'test b' }),
    new Entry({ entry: 'test c' })
]);

MyApp.start({entry: ents});
```

});

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/screen.css">
        <title>Simple Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id = "formBox">
        </div>

        <div id = "listBox">
    </div>
    <script type="text/template" id="form-template">
            <input id = "a" placeholder = "a" autofocus>
            <br />
            <input id = "b" placeholder = "b">
            <br />
            <textarea id = "c" placeholder = "c"></textarea>
            <br />
            <button id = "processInput" >process</button>
        </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="entries-template">
            <thead>
                <tr class='header'>
                    <th>Entry</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </script>
        <script type="text/template" id="entry-template">
            <td><%- entry %></td>
            <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
        </script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try `this.$el.hide()`?

Comment: That has the same effect as "$('.form').hide()" it disappears and than immediately reappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Vp3A/

It appears that the button is getting an implicit type of "submit". Returning false fixes the issue.

```
hideForm : function(){
    //$('.form').css('display','none')
    //document.getElementById("form").style.display="none";
    //$('.form').hide();
    this.$el.hide(); // This is cached on the object. Best to use it.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes the other possible solution is to go to FormView and change the tagname to 'div' instead of 'form' then you wont need to return false.  But eitherway works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.form').css({"display":"none"});
```

This will hide the form as if it didn't exist in the code.

Or (@Makis192 solution)

```
$('.form').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Which will hide the from but still show the blank space